# Не понимаю почему выводятся числа в консоли при выводе массива

Tags: c++, массивы

> Задача: заполнить массив из 50-ти элементов нечётными числами от 1до 99.

```
int main()
{
    int mass[50];
    int pos[99];

    for (int i = 1; i < std::size(pos); i++) 
        pos[i] = i; // Заполняем массив числами по порядку


    for (int i = 0; i < std::size(mass); i++) {
        if (pos[i] % 2 != 0) {
            mass[i] = pos[i];
        } // Проверяем на нечётность и записываем только числа, прошедшие проверку
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < std::size(mass); i++) {
        std::cout << "\n" << mass[i]; // Выводим числа
    }
}
```

Это работает правильно, но на консоль помимо нечётных чисел выводятся ещё какие-то:

> Вывод на консоль:

```
-858993460
1
-858993460
3
-858993460
5
-858993460
7
-858993460
9
-858993460
11
-858993460
13
-858993460
15
-858993460
17
-858993460
19
-858993460
21
-858993460
23
-858993460
25
-858993460
27
-858993460
29
-858993460
31
-858993460
33
-858993460
35
-858993460
37
-858993460
39
-858993460
41
-858993460
43
-858993460
45
-858993460
47
-858993460
49
```

Я думаю, что это их адреса в памяти, но зачем и почему они выводятся?

Comment: `for (std::size_t i = 0; i < std::size(mass); i++) mass[i] = i*2+1;`. Дополнительный массив не нужен.

Comment: Ну или так: `for (std::size_t i = 0, odd = 1; i < std::size(mass); i +=1, odd +=2) mass[i] = odd;`.

Answer (score 2):

Ну-ка, посмотрим...

```
for (int i = 0; i < std::size(mass); i++) {
    if (pos[i] % 2 != 0) {
        mass[i] = pos[i];
    } // Проверяем на нечётность и записываем только числа, прошедшие проверку
}
```

А если число **НЕ** прошло проверку, что с ним делаем? Не записываем. Т.е. `mass[i]` в этом случае так и остается со своим прежним (мусорным) содержимым... Каковое затем и выводится.

Можно так:

```
int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < std::size(mass); i++) {
    if (pos[i] % 2 != 0) {
        mass[k++] = pos[i];
    } // Проверяем на нечётность и записываем только числа, прошедшие проверку
}
```

По окончании кода в `k` количество заполненных элементов массива `mass`.

Но вообще-то **исходная** задача решается так:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) mas[i] = i*2+1;
```

Comment: Хм.. То есть мне нужно выводить массив сразу при проверке. Но если мне этот массив понадобится в будущем, то придётся каждый раз делать эту проверку на нечётность. Что делать в этом случае? Нужно как-то кучковать элементы массива

Comment: А подумать?... См. дополненный ответ.